# Android listview within a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have an app with 2 tabs. Each tab has it's respective fragment. On one of the tabs I would need to place a listview in order to receive data from stored arrays and place them as a list.

This is my code till now:

```
public class Frag3 extends Fragment{


    ListView lv1;
    ProgressDialog ShowProgress;
    public ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    TextView tv1;
    Button button1;

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
          return null;
       }
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);
                //View tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                View listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

               String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
               "Linux", "OS/2" };

               ArrayAdapter<String> files = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                        values);

                lv1.setAdapter(files);

        return view;
    }

}
```

I've tried various options from different web references however none of them seemed to work. Can someone kindly guide me towards a way forward as I'm lost right now and can't seem to understand the next steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest issue is mis-matched variable names.  You call out `lv1` as a class member and set a list adatper against that, but you use `listView` to find the view.  One of those needs to change.

The following change ought to help out:

```
lv1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListView1);        
        listView.setAdapter(files);
```

Try doing this in your code

Answer (score 2):

Try extending `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`.  This will give you the functionality like `onListItemClick` for your list.  You can also use `getListView()` when extending `ListFragment`.  Then in your xml you can use the android `list` id:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your onActivityCreated() you can set your list adapter with [setListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) without having to use `findViewById`

Comment: If you override the onCreateView in the ListFragment, this, seems by far, the best way to go if you create the layout in xml.